# selected query result placing in more DIVs

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to select 3 testimonials at a stretch from the database.. It is ok for me. But my problem is I need place this 3 testimonials in 3 DIVs in the same time.. can anybody tell me how can I do this?

```
    $q = "SELECT * FROM testimonials ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

   while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {


   }

 echo '<div class="testimonial-1">
                   <p>'. $testimonial. '</p>
                  </div>';

 echo '<div class="testimonial-2">
                   <p>'. $testimonial. '</p>
                  </div>';

 echo '<div class="testimonial-3">
                   <p>'. $testimonial. '</p>
                  </div>';
```

Thank you..

Comment: Whats the value of $testimonal? Where does that get set up?  I am assuming you want to use values retrieved from the database, but im not seeing code for that. Also, it seems like your querying is only returning 1 result back, not your desired number of rows.

Comment: my table have id and testimonials columns. query select 3 testimonials and them place in $testimonial.. Im confusing to code in while loop..

Comment: so you are trying to display only three testimonials?

Comment: no. always I need to display 3 randomly selected testimonials.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with mysqli since iam still using mysql..but i can still give you my personal approach regarding your question:

```
$class_ctr = 1;
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
    echo '<div class="testimonial-'.$class_ctr.'">
        <p>'. $row['column_name_to_display']. '</p>
    </div>';
    $class_ctr++;
}
?>
```

Hope this gives you the idea.

Comment: I think this method is not match with me because there are other DIVs and HTML elements with different class names and ids in my main testimonials div..

Comment: yes.. I tried my actual query has id, testimonials, image, name, address from 3 tables. in a one testimonial DIV  I need place these details..and so on. Thats why I use so many DIVs and Tags in my main DIV..

Comment: i think the provided solution above could hold those values:) try it including the real styles of your deisgn..

Answer (score 1):

```
$maxTestimonials = 3;
$query = "SELECT * FROM testimonials ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $maxTestimonials";
$results = mysqli_query($databaseConnection, $query);

$count = 0;
$testimonialsTemplate = '<div class="testimonial-%d"><p>%s</p></div>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $count++;
    echo sprintf($testimonialsTemplate, $count, $row['column_name_to_display']);
}
```

I'd also suggest you look into [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) which will help you to structure your code in a slightly more maintainable (and reusable) fashion.